# Why gdb "set" command doesn't recognize global variable, must add "::" or "variable"?

Tags: c, variables, gdb, set, global

I was trying to set value in gdb, I have:

```
int i=0;
int main(){
  ++i;
  int j=i+2;
  return 0;
}
```

break at "return", and "r"

```
(gdb) set j=4
(gdb) set i=5
Ambiguous set command "i=5": .
(gdb) set ::i=6
(gdb) set variable i=6
```

It's weird, "j" is local variable in main, so "set" with no problem.
While "i" is a global one, seems I should add either "::" or "variable" to make it set.

I searched internet, and it says "variable" is used to set gdb/reg variables used inside debugging sesssion.

Why "i" still requires "variable"?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your example is:

```
(gdb) set i=5
Ambiguous set command "i=5": .
```

This is not a name lookup error but rather the consequence of how gdb parses commands.  (That trailing `: .` looks like it ought to mean something, or list something; but it just seems odd.)

`set` can be used to evaluate an expression, as you discovered with `set j = 4` -- but this only happens because there is no gdb command starting with `set j`.

That is, `set` tries any matching subcommands first, recognizing abbreviations.  And since there are multiple commands starting `set i` (such as `set inferior-tty`, `set input-radix`, ...), gdb doesn't know which to choose.  So, it complains that the command is ambiguous.

The real command to set a variable is `set variable`, which is why the final try worked.

Note that other commands taking an expression can also evaluate an assignment.  I tend to use `p` (aka `print`) interactively rather than `set variable` just because it is shorter.